# Use v-bind in a scss (sass) variable VueJS

Tags: css, vue.js, sass

I'm working on a component in VueJs and I want to make a color attribute that take hexadecimal color and convert into rgb color with rgba function of sass and work with it.

```js
props: {
    color: {
        type: String,
        default: '#195cff'
    }
}
```

I tried to do it like this:

```scss
$color: v-bind(color);

input {
    background: rgba($color, 0.5);
}
```

But I think v-bind is not accessible in sass variable. How can I do this work.

Comment: You can't make it work. SASS variables don't exist at the time when the app runs. You could use CSS variables for that. You may want to not make it harder and just apply colors directly to `style`

Comment: Use class bindings. Or, Have the color supplied from vue properties instead of sass variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's strictly impossible but I found a way to have a similar result.

```js
props: {
        color: {
            type: String,
            default: '#195cff',
        },
    },
    methods: {
        hexToRgb(hex) {
            let result = /^#?([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})$/i.exec(hex);
            return result ? {
                r: parseInt(result[1], 16),
                g: parseInt(result[2], 16),
                b: parseInt(result[3], 16)
            } : null;
        }
    },
    data: function () {
        return {
            rgbColor: `${this.hexToRgb(this.color).r},${this.hexToRgb(this.color).g},${this.hexToRgb(this.color).b}`
        }
    }
```

And in css

```css
input {
    background: rgb(v-bind(rgbColor),0.5);
}
```

Comment: Except it is allowed by Vue via v-bind(): https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-css-features.html#v-bind-in-css